# How to know the type of HTML5 specification used?

Tags: html, markup, specifications

I am currently reading about HTML5 and it was mentioned that there are two specifications available for developer:

1. W3C HTML5 Specifications
2. WHATWG HTML5 Living Standard

My question is, is there is an way to distinguish a website developed by the first type from those developed by the second one? What's the difference between the two types?

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: Check out this blogpost on the topic https://developer.telerik.com/featured/w3c-vs-whatwg-html5-specs-differences-documented/

Comment: Note that asking for the differences between the specifications is way too broad. So you might want to remove this side question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to distinguish which specification(s) the author followed.

Since HTML5, the DOCTYPE no longer contains a version indicator. See [W3C’s HTML WG decision from 2010](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2010Dec/0135.html).

You could of course try to find if the author used something which is allowed in only one of the specifications, but even then, it could be the case that the author used things from both specifications, or copy-pasted a snippet, or followed a draft, or didn’t use a specification to begin with.

A good example is the `hgroup` element. It’s [part of WHATWG’s HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-hgroup-element), but it’s not part of W3C’s HTML5 REC or HTML 5.1 REC. However, it was [part of earlier W3C HTML5 drafts](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html). So if you find a document that contains a `hgroup` element, it could be the case that the author used WHATWG’s HTML, but it could also be the case that the author used a W3C HTML5 draft.

Answer (score -1):

**W3C is the main international standards organization for the World Wide Web.**

**WHATWG is a standard for just html5 and not the world wide web.**

This is the main difference between the two.

It is possible to distinguish the two because they both are part of the world wide web.

Comment: WHATWG does [more than just HTML](https://whatwg.org/specs). The W3C is not a sole authority over all the W3, despite its name. Implementations of HTML do by and large follow the Living Standard over the often-dated W3C spec.

Comment: I'm just giving the basic idea